How to identify and print which constraints are violated in OptaPy?
I'm working on a scheduling optimization project using OptaPy, where I've defined several hard and soft constraints like room conflicts, teacher conflicts, student group conflicts, etc. The problem solves successfully, but I need to know which specific constraints are violated after solving the problem.
Here’s an example of the constraints I’ve defined:
from optapy import constraint_provider
from optapy.constraint import Joiners, ConstraintFactory
from optapy.score import HardSoftScore

@constraint_provider
def define_constraints(constraint_factory: ConstraintFactory):
    return [
        room_conflict(constraint_factory),
        teacher_conflict(constraint_factory),
        student_group_conflict(constraint_factory),
        # other constraints...
    ]

def room_conflict(constraint_factory: ConstraintFactory):
    return constraint_factory.for_each(Lesson) \
        .join(Lesson,
              Joiners.equal(lambda lesson: lesson.timeslot),
              Joiners.equal(lambda lesson: lesson.allotted_room),
              Joiners.less_than(lambda lesson: lesson.id)) \
        .penalize("Room conflict", HardSoftScore.ONE_HARD)

I want to print out which constraints were violated after the solution is found. I’ve tried using solution.getScore().explain(), but I encountered this error:
AttributeError: 'proxy.TimeTable' object has no attribute 'getScore'
I’m not sure how to debug which constraints are being violated or how to print them out.
What is the best way to retrieve information about constraint violations in OptaPy? How can I print out which constraints were violated and their details?
Any help would be appreciated!

The OptaPy project was discontinued and replaced by Timefold Solver.
